# Platform of docker-image AWS ECR

Tags: docker, docker-image, amazon-ecr

How can I know what is the platform of specific docker image (linux/windows for example) in ECR?

I couldn't find it in AWS documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.